# Service Fabric port issue Guest executable web api

Tags: port, azure-service-fabric

Implementing [this tutorial](https://www.erbrech.com/blog/2016/11/01/Hosting-a-web-application-in-Service-Fabric.html) on asp.net web api.
Passing the port in manifest to the guest executable web api. 
[image]

But when the exe launches it gets error saying the port is in use. The Log looks like this. Here the exe automatically picks the next port(as coded).

```
1.4.0 error in port http://localhost:3447/Application1/Guest1 Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
1.4.0 Listening to url http://localhost:3448/Application1/Guest1
```

Does it mean that the port used by serviceManifest, cannot be used by guest executable?
Since servicemanfest-application is reachable on 3447 and guest-executable reachable on 3448, how to access the guest-executablefrom outside?
At the moment I can access the application inside the node machine (rdp) on 3448. But not on Cluster url.

Comment: Could you try to change the Port value to 3448?

Comment: @OlegKarasik That is a good idea, how can I do that? redeploy won't work I guess.

Comment: Do you can delete this application in SF explorer and deploy it again with the modifications in the manifest? Or it is active and used by users?

Comment: @OlegKarasik if I deploy again the same problem happens again. which ever IP I give in manifest wont connect with guest executable. So if we give port 1 , then Sf manifest gets 1 and guest application has to use 2( or any other number)

Comment: Are you testing it on local cluster or in the azure?

Comment: yes , tested there as well, same issue, both local and azure cluster same behavior

Comment: On the local cluster how many nodes did you have? and how many service instances did you specify in `ApplicationManifest.xml`? Can you try this on local cluster with one node with one instance of the service mapped to port 5000?

Comment: 1 on both applicationmanifest -1 (all)

Comment: Could you try to add a probe and a load balancer rule to listen to the port? It's just a try.

Comment: To listen to which port? 3448 or 3447?

Comment: To listen port 3448.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT, sorry not working

Comment: opened a port in node for 3448, still doesn't connect from outside